# Kazhdan's property T for Kahler surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, dg.differential-geometry

Is it true that the fundamental groups of compact Kahler surfaces have property T if and only if it they are finite? I am having trouble finding counterexamples to this, but maybe that's just me...

Comment: Igor, if you add the assumption that the fundamental group is Gromov-hyperbolic, then it becomes a very interesting question to which currently there are no counter-examples. 

Comment: @Misha: Isn't it hard just to find a hyperbolic group with prop T?

Comment: @Igor Rivin: Igor, there are several ways to construct hyperbolic groups with property T. The oldest: (1) Uniform lattices in quaternionic hyperbolic space. More recent: (2)  Fundamental groups of 2-dimensional simplicial complexes where links of vertices have smallest eigenvalue $>1/2$. (3) Uniform lattices acting on some hyperbolic buildings. (4) Random groups (in certain regimes) are infinite hyperbolic with property T. Very recent: (5) Oppenheim's constructions. However, it is conjectured that 2-dimensional (hyperbolic) groups are never Kahler (except for surface groups).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this [survey](http://library.msri.org/books/Book28/files/arapura.pdf) by Donu Arapura, Toledo proved that many arithmetic lattices in higher rank algebraic $\mathbb{Q}$-groups (with hermitian symmetric space) are fundamental groups of smooth *projective* surfaces.

In particular $Sp(2n,\mathbb{Z})$ for $n>2$, is such a group, and has property (T).

Note that once you get a group as fundamental group of a smooth projective variety you obtain a smooth projective surface with the same fundamental group by intersecting with some generic hyperplanes.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That certainly does it...